# How to validate same selected value in 2 select boxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 select boxes I want to check and give error if both of select boxes have same selected value.

```
<select>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>


<select>
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>
```

I want to achieve it by Angular Js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jydj0v4q/1/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks it works I want to promt alert box for it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jydj0v4q/2/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a watch over to 2 model values to show the alert like

```
<select ng-model="x">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>


<select ng-model="y">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

then

```
$scope.$watch('[x, y]', function () {
    if ($scope.x && $scope.x == $scope.y) {
        alert('error')
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jydj0v4q/)

Answer (score 0):

bind two select tags as below and compare values

```
<select ng-model="select1">
 <option>A</option>
 <option>B</option>
 <option>C</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="select2">
 <option>A</option>
 <option>B</option>
 <option>C</option>
</select>
```

check values